# regular expression .* matches different characters

Tags: regex, r

I have trouble understanding the following results

```
>f <- "anno_26//anno_-1_5_252138_4817.rds"
>sub("anno_26//anno_.*?_(.*?)_.*?_.*", "", f)
[1] "4817.rd"
>sub("anno_26//anno_.*?_.*?_(.*?)_.*", "", f)
[1] ""
```

Why in the former regular expression, ".*" doesn't match anything while in the latter it corresponds to 4817.rd ?

Comment: Your regex seem valid, you can check the regex match function on https://regex101.com/  . Why are you using re.sub?

Comment: What exactly do you need to get? Explaining the pattern questions are not welcome, so please specify the expected output so that we could provide relevant help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve, but using back references might help you progress:

```
f <- "anno_26//anno_-1_5_252138_4817.rds"

sub("(anno_26\\/\\/anno_.*?_)(.*?)(_.*?_.*)", "\\1\\3", f, perl=TRUE)
[1] "anno_26//anno_-1__252138_4817.rds"

sub("(anno_26\\/\\/anno_.*?_.*?_)(.*?)(_.*)", "\\1\\3", f, perl=TRUE)
[1] "anno_26//anno_-1_5__4817.rds"
```